# Unable to send mail from C# App using godaddy details

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Despite spending an entire morning with GoDaddy chat, and reading almost everything I can find on sending emails via godaddy I am still no closer to solving my issue.

**What Have I tried**

Firstly, this is my code.

```
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net")
        // var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25)
        {
            Port = 25,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            EnableSsl = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@User.com", "Password@"),
         //   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,

    };
```

and I think I should mention that this works when I attempt to use google's free smpt server, the mail is sent. However using my godaddy credentials, I get the following error,
`Message = "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 72.167.234.197 (72.167.234.197:25), connect error 10060"` other times it says

`InnerException = {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}`

I have also tried other suggested ports like 587 , 80, 3552. Nothing has changed, I have also tried the suggestion at this link https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-email-using-systemnetmail-19291 . Which did not work (no suprise to me, cause where am i putting the account password) . Would appreciate it if anyone has solved getting their C# application to work with Godaddy. Like I said it works with Google so I dont believe my code is an issue in anyway.

regards

Comment: secureserver.net is hosted by Godaddy? What port do they host on? Do they require SSL? What does their documentation and support people say?

Comment: They require SSL, you can find the details here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/server-and-port-settings-for-workspace-email-6949

Comment: This is something you need to ask your hosting provider about the settings that you need to use in order to send email.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, however, one way to test if you are using the correct smtp settings is to send the email with a program like Microsoft Outlook or Thunderbird.  Also, if you are using a dedicated server or a VPS, you need to use

```
dedrelay.secureserver.net
```

See: https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-servers-email-relay-server-16601

Also, check out this see: https://in.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Unable-to-send-email-from-C-net-application-from-website/m-p/102913#M1256

which mentions: "*If you are using a Plesk shared hosting plan, use **relay-hosting.secureserver.net and port 25**. *Do not specify a* username or password. Other relay/smtp servers will not work from our shared hosting.*"

Comment: I tried your smpt server and it still does not work.
I'm not entirely sure if its a pleck hosting but I also tried your second server, i didnt specify a username and password(something I find odd) but even that failed to work.

Comment: You said you contacted GoDaddy and you were not able to solve the problem. Have you checked the DNS records to make sure they correctly set. Did you try Outlook or Thunderbird? If nothing works, your DNS is messed up, try to reset it.